# PowerShell PowerBI cmdlets find Linked/Shared DataSets

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powershell-cmdlet

My reports uses a PowerBI DataSet as a Datasource.
Is there a way with PowerShell to find what Linked/Shared dataset this is.
Get-PowerBIDatasource  nor Get-PowerBIDataSet  does list  them ...

Kr, Harry

Answer (score 0):

[Get-PowerBIReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.reports/get-powerbireport?view=powerbi-ps) will tell you the Id of the dataset in [DatasetId property](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/src/Common/Common.Api/Reports/Report.cs) (also take a look at the [raw REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup)). You can't tell directly is it shared or not - you must enumerate all report and get the DatasetIds used to decide are there datasets used in more than one report. You can also use [Get-PowerBIDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.data/get-powerbidataset?view=powerbi-ps) and compare the name of the report and the name of the dataset. If they are different, then most likely this dataset is shared between repots.